# Stopping the NSApplication main event loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsapplication

I have an application consisting of the following single `.m` file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  [[[NSThread alloc] initWithBlock: ^{
    sleep(2);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
      NSLog(@"Stop");
      [[NSApplication sharedApplication] stop:nil];
    });
  }] start];
  [[NSApplication sharedApplication] run];
  NSLog(@"Run finished");
  return 0;
}
```

According to [the developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428473-stop), `stop` should stop the main loop (`run`), but it doesn't (at least not on OS X 10.12 and 10.13). There's also [`terminate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428417-terminate), but this exits the program too soon. I also tried setting an `NSApplicationDelegate` that implements `applicationShouldTerminate`, but this is never called.

How can I make sure the main run loop is (cleanly) exited?

*Note:* The shared application main loop is necessary because there is UI work being done elsewhere. More concretely, this is giving problems in the [Go WDE](https://github.com/skelterjohn/go.wde) UI library, which uses Cocoa to provide a window to a Go application.

Comment: There isn't enough context to answer the question.   Off the cuff, if you're writing a command line tool, it should be structured as a command line tool and not use NSApplication at all.

Comment: @bbum I didn't add any context because it didn't seem relevant to the problem, and would only complicate the question. Anyway, added the context of the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for `-stop:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428473-stop?language=objc) says:

> [C]alling this method from a timer or run-loop observer routine would not stop the run loop because they do not result in the posting of an NSEvent object.

A block dispatched to the main queue is similar in that it doesn't post an event. You can try posting an `NSEventTypeApplicationDefined` event after calling `-stop:`.

Answer (score 2):

After investigating this further, it seems that the UI loop `stop` request is only processed after a *UI* event (so not just after a main loop event). So, it works in response to a UI event, but not in a thread like I did in my example.

Triggering a UI event after a `stop` request (e.g. a programmatic resize works for me) causes the loop to end.