# How to stop() main thread NSApp run() event loop? (embedded in C++)

Tags: objective-c++, nsapplication

Here is a minimal reproductible example, if too long to read, go to next section with the problem, and then explore the code if needed.

### Minimal example:

Let suppose a simple C++ command line:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Wrapper.h"
int main()
{
    Wrapper wrapper;
    wrapper.run();
    std::cout << "Exiting" << std::endl;
}
```

The Objective-C wrapper header: Wrapper.h

```
struct OCWrapper;
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper() noexcept;
    virtual ~Wrapper() noexcept;
    void run();
private:
    OCWrapper* impl=nullptr;
};
```

And it implementation: Wrapper.mm

```
#import "Wrapper.h"
#import "MyOCApp.h"

struct OCWrapper
{
    MyOCApp* wrapped=nullptr;
};

Wrapper::Wrapper() noexcept: impl(new OCWrapper)
{
    impl->wrapped = [[ MyOCApp alloc] init];
}

Wrapper::~Wrapper() noexcept
{
    [impl->wrapped release];
    delete impl;
}

void Wrapper::run()
{
    [impl->wrapped run];
}
```

And finally the interesting part, in Objective-C, MyOCApp.h:

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyOCApp: NSObject
@end

@implementation MyOCApp
- (id)init 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                selector:@selector(applicationDidFinishLaunching:)
                name:NSApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object:nil];
    
    return self;
}

- (void)run
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(shutdown:) withObject:nil afterDelay: 2];
    //CFRunLoopRun();
    
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [NSApp run];
}

- (void) shutdown:(NSNotification *) notif
{
    NSLog(@"Stopping");
    //CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
    [NSApp stop:self];
}

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *) notif
{
    NSLog(@"Application ready");
}
@end
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10.0)
cmake_policy( SET CMP0076 NEW)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project(ocapp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})

find_library(APP_KIT AppKit)
find_library(CORE_FOUNDATION CoreFoundation)
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${APP_KIT} ${CORE_FOUNDATION} )

target_sources( ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "main.cpp" "Wrapper.mm" PUBLIC "Wrapper.h" "MyOCApp.h" )
```

The project can be built with following commands:

> $ cmake -G Xcode .
> $ open ocapp.xcodeproj

### The problem:

When using `[NSApp run]` and `[NSApp stop:self]`, I am unable to stop the event loop, so it keep running indefinitely.

> Application finished launching
> Stopping
> .....
> Killed: 9

When using `CFRunLoopRun()` and `CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())`, it start/stop correctly, but `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is never triggered.

> Stopping
> Terminating

### The question:

Why is this? and how to have both feature working?

Comment: The signature of `didFinishLaunching` should be `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` instead. I'm surprised you'd need to subscribe to it manually.

Comment: I fixed the code in the question, and added a CMAKE file.

Comment: Is there any reason why are you not calling `NSApplicationMain` from your `main` instead and presumably designating your `MyOCApp` as the `NSApplicationDelegate`? Are you trying to make a GUI Cocoa/AppKit App?

Comment: This is just a minimal example, in the real project the C++ part is much larger, and the Objective-C part is just to gather some events from macOS (also most of the project is cross-platform).  Answering your question, no Cocoa, as minimal as possible AppKit. So using NSApplicationMain makes the Objective_C part even more intrusive in the project (which already needed significant refactoring to allow the main thread to be monopolized by NSApp::run).

Comment: But obviously, if a solution without changing main.cpp works, I don't really care about NSApplicationMain, NSApplicationDelegate, or NSWhatever. Feel free to show your ideas as answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't in the attached code. Your existing variant

```
[NSApplication sharedApplication];
[NSApp run];
```

and

```
[NSApp stop:self];
```

is correct.

The culprit is your `CMakeLists.txt`. The one you included creates an executable binary. That's fine for a console app but it's not a valid MacOS app consisting of AppName.app folder and bunch of other files. Since you're using AppKit API without proper scaffold of an MacOS app it doesn't work.

A *bare minimum fix* in your `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE
)
```

Now you will have a correct App target in Xcode. You can look up more advanced examples of `CMakeLists.txt` suitable for MacOS apps on the Internet.

**Update**
So I investigated it further and inspected the exit routine in
`-[NSApplication run]` (`+[NSApp run]` is a synonym left for compatibility but the real implementation is in `-[NSApplication run]`).
We can set a symbolic breakpoint through lldb like this:
`b "-[NSApplication run]"` the snippet of interest (for X86-64) is:

```
->  0x7fff4f5f96ff <+1074>: add    rsp, 0x98
    0x7fff4f5f9706 <+1081>: pop    rbx
    0x7fff4f5f9707 <+1082>: pop    r12
    0x7fff4f5f9709 <+1084>: pop    r13
    0x7fff4f5f970b <+1086>: pop    r14
    0x7fff4f5f970d <+1088>: pop    r15
    0x7fff4f5f970f <+1090>: pop    rbp
    0x7fff4f5f9710 <+1091>: ret
```

We can verify that a breakpoint where arrow points is hit only in the bundled variant but not in the "naked" executable variant. After further research I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48064763/5329717 which is *very* helpful. The key quote by @Remko being:

> it seems that the UI loop stop request is only processed after a UI
> event (so not just after a main loop event).

And that is indeed the case. If in the "naked" executable variant we add

```
- (void) shutdown:(NSNotification *) notif
{
    NSLog(@"Stopping");
    //CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
    [NSApp stop:self];
    [NSApp abortModal]; //this is used for generating a UI NSEvent
}
```

We get desired behavior and the app terminates normally. So your "naked" app variant isn't a correct MacOS app, hence it does not receive UI events (its runloop works correctly regardless).

On the other hand having proper MacOS app bundle with `Info.plist` etc is necessary for MacOS to setup an app window , Dock icon etc.

In the long run I do recommend either going for pure console app if you don't need AppKit at all or doing things by the book. Otherwise you will run into such anomalies.

Comment: Hi Kamil.S, Thanks for your answer. Do you have an explanation why executing the bundle (`open ...`) works, while executing the binary inside (`./ocapp.app/...../ocapp`) does not? Up to now, to me, the bundles was just a way to pack conveniently libraries and other required files for the executable.

Comment: So I did check and the Chess app works only when the executable is inside the `Chess.app` bundle folder. If you move the executable somewhere else it won't work. That mimics your problem. And the MacOS when starting an UI app needs `Info.plist` file.

Comment: I still miss some explanation: Why is this? It is IMHO not acceptable to push a software which freeze while run through the binary. I feel like the bundle is solving the problem "by casualty" rather than for a specific OS requirement.

Comment: Thank you. This bring light to the topic.